# When parameter is not passed to controller over url

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-routing

In cakephp, I've a controller that should receive a parameter and then call model to work with database to show the result in a view. Pretty common mvc approach.

Imagine the controller as "Insert a new post" which should be associated to an specific user.

So, the URL should be: `http://mysite/inspost/(user_id).`

The problem is, when URL is like `http://mysite/inspost/`

It will show the same view and will insert the new post even if the user_id has not been specified.

How can I control this?

Comment: You can start by showing us your code...

Comment: Do you have the typical user check `if($user_id == null) throw new NotFoundException()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 2<sup>nd</sup> page of the blog tutorial, [Adding a layer](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html):

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    $this->set('post', $post);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing it now, the tutorial, thanks for that